# how to pass parameters from a file into a script?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I have a Python script that is run like this:

```
scriptname --param_a=123 --param_b=423 --param_c=xyz
```

The script expects to be passed three parameters

I have a (configuration) text file, that contains the parameters. I want to write a Bash script (my first), that will use the entries in the file to pass the parameters to the script.

For example if the configuration text file contains the following data:

```
--param_a=123 --param_b=423 --param_c=xyz
--param_a=203 --param_b=343 --param_c=abz
--param_a=976 --param_b=891 --param_c=abc
```

Then I want to call the script (3 times) once for each line in the config file, and pass the parameters to the script.

Can anyone suggest how to write such a Bash script.

I intend to run the script on an Ubuntu system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read -r -a array
do
    scriptname "${array[@]}"
done < configfile
```

or

```
while read -r line
do
    scriptname $line
done < configfile
```

The advantage to the first one is if your config file had commas, for example, between the parameters instead of spaces:

```
--param_a=123,--param_b=423,--param_c=xyz
```

you could do:

```
while IFS=, read -r -a array
```